# Turning an SQL query into a function taking identifiers

Tags: function, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, dynamic-sql

I have an SQL Query in PostgreSQL to extract `doy` (day of year) from dates. My query is:

```
select extract(doy from date_col) as n
from mytable
order by n
```

I want to turn it into a function like `extract_doy(tablename, date_column_name)`.
How would I do that?

Comment: I think this could work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to return a setof doubles, something like this should work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tmp_extract_doy(table_name text, column_name text) 
RETURNS SETOF DOUBLE PRECISION
AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT EXTRACT(doy from %I) AS n FROM %I ORDER BY n', column_name, table_name);
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  COST 100;
```